# Calculating sums / averages across a subset of a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I'm looking for some SQL expertise, please. I am working to calculate an average, by first aggregating all relevant rows and then dividing by the number of days in my query.

I am unable to get my sums working properly (it just sums to 0 for all rows). Any suggestions? thanks!

---

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging] (
[Ticker] varchar(50),
[Date] float,
[Date 250 Days Ago] float,
[Close] float
)

INSERT INTO [intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging] ([Ticker], [Date])
SELECT [Ticker], CONVERT(float,[DataDate])
FROM [FinData].[dbo].[Date_Ticker_Shell$]
WHERE [Date_Ticker_Shell$].[DataDate] between '01/2/2007' AND '10/26/2015'


UPDATE [intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging]
SET [Date 250 Days Ago]=CONVERT(float,[Date Calculations].[Date 250 Days Ago])
FROM [Date Calculations]
WHERE [intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging].[Date]=[Date Calculations].[Date]

UPDATE [intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging]
SET [Close]=[dailyOHLC].[Close]
FROM [dailyOHLC]
WHERE [intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging].[Date]=[dailyOHLC].[Date] And [intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging].[Ticker]=[dailyOHLC].[Ticker]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices] (
[Ticker] varchar(50),
[Date] float,
[Date 250 Days Ago] float,
[Close] float,
[Aggregated 250 Day Closing Prices] float,
[Average 250 Day Price] float
)

INSERT INTO [intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices] ([Ticker], [Date], [Date 250 Days Ago], [Close], [Aggregated 250 Day Closing Prices])
SELECT [Ticker], [Date], [Date 250 Days Ago], [Close],
SUM(CASE WHEN [Date] between [Date] AND [Date 250 Days Ago] THEN [Close] ELSE 0 END) [Aggregated 250 Day Closing Prices]
FROM [FinData].[dbo].[intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging]
GROUP BY [Ticker], [Date], [Date 250 Days Ago], [Close]
```

Comment: Why are you converting your dates to `FLOAT`?

Comment: Hey man, that was be scrapping the bottom of the barrel in terms of troubleshooting. Doesn't seem to make a difference when used as a string. thanks

Comment: NOTE: You cannot use between with a bigger value before the smaller value. e.g. Nothing will be between 5 and 1, some things may be between 1 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you converting your dates to numbers?  SQL Server has very good date functions and operators.  You should use them.

However, your problem is the `between`, I think.  Assuming that `[Date 250 Days Ago]` is earlier than `[Date]`, then your bounds are in the wrong order.  The first bound for `between` needs to be less than the second bound.

So try:

```
SELECT [Ticker], [Date], [Date 250 Days Ago], [Close],
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Date] between [Date 250 Days Ago] AND [Date] 
                THEN [Close] ELSE 0 END) as [Aggregated 250 Day Closing Prices]
FROM [FinData].[dbo].[intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging]
GROUP BY [Ticker], [Date], [Date 250 Days Ago], [Close];
```

Seeing that, I think you only want `[Ticker]` in the `GROUP BY`.  So I'm guessing you really want:

```
SELECT [Ticker],
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Date] between [Date 250 Days Ago] AND [Date] 
                THEN [Close] ELSE 0 END) as [Aggregated 250 Day Closing Prices]
FROM [FinData].[dbo].[intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging]
GROUP BY [Ticker]
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks very much, Gordon. I cleaned up the code as you suggested, but my sum is now aggregating across all dates in the universe, as opposed to the specified range of dates I am attempting to reference in the Staging table.

To be clear, I am looking for daily, rolling 1 year averages, so my final output would need to include Ticker and Date so that I get 1 line, per ticker, per day (if that makes sense). Any direction you could point me in would be fantastic!
thanks

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging] (
[Ticker] varchar(50),
[Date] datetime,
[Date 250 Days Ago] datetime,
[Close] float
)

INSERT INTO [intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging] ([Ticker], [Date])
SELECT [Ticker], [DataDate]
FROM [FinData].[dbo].[Date_Ticker_Shell$]
WHERE [Date_Ticker_Shell$].[DataDate] between '01/2/2007' AND '10/26/2015'

UPDATE [intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging]
SET [Date 250 Days Ago]=[Date Calculations].[Date 250 Days Ago]
FROM [Date Calculations]
WHERE [intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging].[Date]=[Date Calculations].[Date]

UPDATE [intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging]
SET [Close]=[dailyOHLC].[Close]
FROM [dailyOHLC]
WHERE [intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging].[Date]=[dailyOHLC].[Date] And [intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging].[Ticker]=[dailyOHLC].[Ticker]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices] (
[Ticker] varchar(50),
[Date] datetime,
[Date 250 Days Ago] datetime,
[Close] float,
[Aggregated 250 Day Closing Prices] float,
[Average 250 Day Price] float
)

INSERT INTO [intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices] ([Ticker],[Aggregated 250 Day Closing Prices])
SELECT [Ticker],
SUM(CASE WHEN [Date] between [Date 250 Days Ago] AND [Date] 
THEN [Close] ELSE 0 END) as [Aggregated 250 Day Closing Prices]
FROM [FinData].[dbo].[intradayOHLC_Selected_Closing_Prices_Staging]
GROUP BY [Ticker]
```